# Video player for time interval measurement

Tags: windows-7, video

I'm trying to figure out how many milliseconds passed between two events in a video. But most players I tried have 1 second resolution in the time label.

What are the players that show higher resolution time labels?
What kind of other tools can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VirtualDub, and it does the job pretty well

http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/